# HTML5 Video playing LAN

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video, lan

I use HTML5 `<video>` tag to play videos in my LAN from different computers. In my current setup, I have got a server, which provides the html page and all the videos I want to play. There are some computers which should play these videos by loading the html page. In general that works already. But sometimes after a while playing a video, the console says **failed to load resource** and the playing stops immediately. I thougt, this is maybe some sort of timeout in my LAN and I had the idea to play the videos locally, i.e. copy all videos to each computer and just provide the html on the server. The server html then, just links to `file://.../`.

**but** when I tried this approach on the server, the video was stopping every few seconds and it did not buffer at all. It was completely impossible to watch the video. 
Videos are *.mp4; I run chrome on all win7 computers, Server is XAMPP.

Is there either a way to catch the **failed to load resource** error, or a way to play local videos in a reasonable quality?

Did none of you have problems like that yet?

Comment: It seems to be prevented from playing because of security settings (and for good reason!) But there seems to be a workaround posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885701/play-local-hard-drive-video-file-with-html5-video-tag

Another option would be to install a simple webserver serving the video files on the lan

Comment: I have a simple webserver (xampp), but - i don't know why - there is a error after a litte while. I will try the workaround!

Comment: Does someone know, what that win means in the example of @Flunk http://jsfiddle.net/dsbonev/cCCZ2/embedded/result,js,html,css/presentation/ ? I can't make the URL load correctly

Comment: @Flunk or: is it possible to change the security settings to allow a larger buffer?

Comment: What resource is the browser failing to load?

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts:

- does your config include 'AddType video/mp4 .mp4'?
- is it possible that progressive loading has been disabled somehow?
- how large are the videos? there are reports of > 30Mb files having playback issues in XAMPP
- if you convert to another format ( .ogg, .avi, similar ) do they playback any better?
- if you use a .php (or similar) file to provide progressive loading - any change? IE Stream from the app instead of directly.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer! Do you mean the "config" and "progressive loading" of my browser? If yes: How can I check both? It is possible, that the videos have a larger size than 30MB, but I am pretty sure, that it also occured with smaller sizes. I will check that again. I think converting all videos wouldn't be an option, because it would take so much time. But if you think it would help finding the answer I can try this with one or two videos. Could you also provide a link that explains progressive loading?

Comment: Use FFMPEG (or similar) to convert a few to .ogg or .flv and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Also - you didn't mention whether or not you support PHP. If so I have some sample code I can include. Otherwise, you might get some traction by searching for 'HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content'.