# Safari: unable to dynamically load video from blob url

Tags: javascript, html5-video, blob

i'm trying to implement a dynamic loading for an html5 video tag.

when a user picks a video file via the `<input type="file">` element, i want to load it dynamically to a `<video>` element, and append it to body.

the following code works on Chrome but not on Safari:

```
function load_video(file) { // this came from <input type="file"> change event
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
        var blob = new Blob([event.target.result]);
        window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        $('body').append('<video controls width="320" src="' + blobURL + '" onloadedmetadata="alert('loaded meta data!')"></video>');
    }
}
```

now,
if i'll replace `src="' + blobURL + '"` with a local filepath, say- `/media/videos/vid1.mp4`, the video loads in Safari as well, but I need it to load the video from `blobURL`.

any suggestions?

thanks alot.

**UPDATE:**

as Rod says, unfortunately it's a known bug in Safari (not supported by it's media backend).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same exact issue with Safari 6.1, getting `MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED` when trying to load a file from an input, like so:

```js
var fileInput = document.querySelector('#file'),
    video = document.querySelector('video');

fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  var file = evt.target.files[0];
  var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
  video.src = url;

  video.addEventListener('error', function(err){
    // This craps out in Safari 6
    console.error(video.error, err);
    alert('nay :(');
  });
});
```

<strike>Try `video.addEventListener('error', logError)` or something to figure out if you have the same issue. I suspect Safari doesn't support yet videos with `blob`-type source.</strike>

**UPDATE**: Yup, it's a bug. See https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=101671 and help us let the webkit maintainers this is something that needs to be fixed.

**UPDATE, 2015**: It works now, updated the code.

Comment: Has this been fixed in later iOS Safari? I'm unable to find any info and the bug has not been updated

Comment: Here you go buddy, a way for you to find out yourself: http://bl.ocks.org/unRob/3bd07a012597aa959c92

Comment: What is that? Is it a page running a Safari backend or just the code that puts a blob url in a video tag?

Comment: Sorry, I thought the code would be self-explanatory. It's a way to test if the bug has been fixed in whatever iOS you'd be willing to test it in; whereas I've seen it work in v9.0, can't really say what will happen to any other versions.

Comment: Ok, the code is exactly the same as what I've tested and I couldn't get it to work on iOS 7.1 so I guess it's not supported. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I don't know if the solution applies to video as well as audio, but I had the same issue with Safari audio and I discovered that the solution was to specify the content type when constructing the blob:

```
var blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], {type: 'audio/mpeg'});
url = webkitURL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

Comment: Seems like this one has just solved my problem when I tried to fetch duration from blob url with the built in audio's loadedmetadata event. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], {type: 'video/mp4'});
```

Comment: This answer needs more explanation that would be better by providing more detail.