# How to record HTML5 video in Safari?

Tags: javascript, php, html, safari

I have to develop video recording in Safari 11. I have used **getUserMedia()** to play video in Safari and It is working but It is not recording the video.

I have developed video recording in Chrome and Mozilla using Media Recorder. 
Media Recorder is not supporting in Safari 11 for recording video.How will i record the video in Safari 11?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this? I am running into similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MediaRecorder** API is not supported on Safari 11. They enabled **MediaRecorder** API on version 12.2, but it is experimental and you should enable it manually. 
Here is good article describing supported properties and methods.

https://blog.addpipe.com/safari-technology-preview-73-adds-limited-mediastream-recorder-api-support/

I am developing same type of app and solved recording problem, however there is other problems too. For example playback recorded video before uploading to the server. You can't do that too, because of known bug

[Safari: unable to dynamically load video from blob url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088400/safari-unable-to-dynamically-load-video-from-blob-url)

Let's hope **webkit** team will fix in the near future.

Comment: how did you solve recording problem?

Comment: @ghazalehjavaheri I don't remember sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Both recording and playback of video seem to work fine in latest Safari after enabling MediaRecorder from Develop menu.
Try with this [Cam Recorder HTML5 demo](https://demo.videowhisper.com/cam-recorder-html5-video-audio/).