# HTML5 video local source + web source

Tags: html, html5-video

I would like my webpage to look for some video files locally first, and then play them from the web if they are not found.  This makes sense for me because I am building a kiosk that will run on someone else's wifi (that may be slow).  I would like to do something like this:

```
<video id="video1" width="420">
    <source src="c:\website\assets\video\mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="\assets\video\mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

This doesn't work for me because the video tag doesn't like that local pathing.  I have seen people online suggesting the following, but I don't really understand how to implement it to solve my problem.  Can anyone help?

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*"/>
<video controls autoplay></video>
```

Comment: Try adding **file:///** before **C:\...**.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I actually solved this by simply installing a local webserver and pointing the first source to localhost, and the second to my website.  Cheers!

Comment: Using a webserver is proberly best but on my computer it works with **file:///**. Does **file:///c:\website\assets\video\mov_bbb.mp4** work if you visit the address directly in the browser ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually solved this by simply installing a local webserver and pointing the first source to localhost, and the second to my website. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The `<input>` solution is discussed here: [Play local (hard-drive) video file with HTML5 video tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885701/play-local-hard-drive-video-file-with-html5-video-tag), but the user must choose the local file to be played. For security reasons I don't think a page can access file:// resources without user intervention.