# Using local file as <audio> src

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

Is it possible to use an audio file from the user's hard drive as the `src` attribute for an HTML5 `<audio>` tag? Maybe through an `<input type="file" />`? This might not be particularly useful in production, but I'm still curious if it can be done.

Comment: You should be able to use the same techniques discussed [Play Local (hard-drive) video.][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885701/play-local-hard-drive-video-file-with-html5-video-tag

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I can think of two ways.

Within your **audio** tag:

```
src="file:///C:/.../file.mp3"
```

or you could use a Blob using the file API.

HTML:

```
<input type="file"></input>
```

JS:

```
audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].files[0]);
```

Comment: nice, the file API method worked like a charm for me!

Comment: also of note. If you want to change the audio tag every time the file changes, there is an 'change' event for the input tag. that will fire every time you change the file in the input tag.

Comment: I just get `Not allowed to load local resource`.  Stupid damn security.  Surely feeding an `.mp3` directly into the `src` of an `audio` element should be supported?

Comment: @AlexMcMillan It should not. Or else, a random script your browser loads, could play through your music collection at once.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on localhost, the mp3 imported via require("...") has a property 'default' which contains the relevant src

```
const MissingAudio = require("../media/missingAudio.mp3");
<audio src={MissingAudio.default}></audio>
```