# HTML5 audio tag cannot play local mp3

Tags: html5-audio

I am trying to load a local mp3 file in the `audio` tag but I get `Not allowed to load local resource` in browser console.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246053/how-can-i-create-a-link-to-a-local-file-on-a-locally-run-web-page) post which says I should be using `file:///` in the `src` but that did not help either.

```
<audio id="myAudio" src="file:///E:\ss.mp3"></audio>
```

[image]

I am using Chrome, Windows 10. Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Local audio cannot be played by using it in `src` of the `audio` tag. This is because browsers are sandboxed and cannot and should not have access to user file system ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052473/go-to-local-url-with-javascript)).

I solved this by adding a file input element that requires user to choose a music file which then can be loaded into the `src` ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737224/using-local-file-as-audio-src), [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074833/using-local-file-for-web-audio-api-in-javascript)).

Answer (score 0):

Local audio can be played only if the document is also a local resource.

Btw, although Chrome accepts backslashes, you should normally use slash for file URIs.