# Trying to play mp3 using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html5-audio

**Goal:**

- Trying to add a background sound to my project with a local file that has a play pause state.

Loading an external URL file seems ok and plays/pauses fine, but not local file.

**Question:**

- Also what is the exact reason a URL http://....mp3 file plays and my local does not?

**Issue:**

- Network status is `Status Code: 206 Partial Content`
- Console error is `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause().`

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="music-player">
        <audio
          ref="audio"
          preload="auto"
          volume="0.1"
          muted
          loop
        >
          <source :src="file" />
        </audio>
        <div @click="toggleSound(file)" class="toggle-sound paused"></div>
      </div>
```

**JS:**

```
    data: () => ({
      ...,
      file: "/public/audio/bg-music.mp3"
    }),
    methods: {
    toggleSound() {
        let audio = this.$refs.audio;
        if (
          audio.paused &&
          document.querySelector(".toggle-sound").classList.contains("paused")
        ) {
          console.log("play it")
          audio.play();
          document.querySelector(".toggle-sound").classList.remove("paused");
        } else {
          console.log("pause it")
          audio.pause();
          document.querySelector(".toggle-sound").classList.add("paused");
        }
      },
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737224/using-local-file-as-audio-src?lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simply added the audio src to the `audio` tag like the below and it worked!

```
<div class="music-player">
    <audio
      ref="audio"
      src="@/assets/audio/bg-music.ogg"
      preload
      loop
      id="audio"
      muted
    ></audio>
    <div @click="toggleSound()" class="toggle-sound"></div>
  </div>
```