# Audio src not working when I implement on Html

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-audio

I want to implement a src location like this

```
 <audio src="D:/Js%20Project/audioPlayer/src/sanail.mp3" controls></audio>
```

but this is not working and I know that

```
<audio src="./src/sanail.mp3"></audio>
```

is working.

This is my source code and this is not working

> ```
> <html lang="en">
>
>     <head>
>         <meta charset="UTF-8">
>         <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
>         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
>         <title>Audio Player</title>
>     </head>
>
>     <body>
>       
>         <audio src="D:/Js%20Project/audioPlayer/src/sanail.mp3" controls></audio>
>     </body>
>
> </html>
> ```

Comment: I think you neeed to use `src=file:///D:.....`. Check this Answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737224/using-local-file-as-audio-src

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai I don't think this works anymore in most browsers.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the structure of your project. But, I think this may work:

```
<audio src="../src/sanail.mp3"></audio>
```

Anyway, I recommend you check this: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

note: If you want the page to be on the web, you can't use local files. All of the resources must be in a hosting (like github pages).

Answer (score -1):

A page can't just load any file from your computer. You should run something like live-server.

1. Install node and npm.
2. In the command line, enter `npm install live-server -G`
3. Navigate to the folder where your project is and enter `live-server`

https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Edit: I realize now that if you're just opening the html file in your browser then you should be able to access local resources. Try it like this:

`<audio src="file:///D:/Js%20Project/audioPlayer/src/sanail.mp3" controls></audio>`

But it definitely won't work this way if you are using a http server like I suggested above.

Comment: You can also use `python3 -m http.server 80`