# Local Audio in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, web

How can I make my html page represent local audio without uploading.
I have code like but the audio is not playing it just represent audio style:

```html
<audio controls preload="none" id="audio"> 
    <source id="first-audio" src="/home/linux/Desktop/Mega/upload/Audio Files/file.wav" type="audio/wav">
 </audio>
```

Comment: FYI: Your code is blank. 

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using local file as <audio> src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737224/using-local-file-as-audio-src)

Comment: You should try to remove the first slash `/` before `home` from `src`, most of the time it creates a problem. See if it works

Comment: Hi @sara : There can only be two reasons that it is not working.

1. Wrong Relative path of the audio file means `src={}` is not pointing to correct audio path.

2. Or wrong `type` or the type of audio not supported.

Can can please show me the file structure. Take a screenshot and add to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Audio Play </title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <audio controls autoplay>
            <source src="https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/m/example.mp3">
        </audio> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Try this, remember to place your audio file in same directory that your html   file or use relative path :

```
 <html>
        <head>
            <title> Audio Play </title>
        </head>
        <body>
             <audio controls autoplay>
                <source src="frere_jacques.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            </audio> 
        </body>
    </html>
```

more infos, to help you : [www.w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp)