# How to load and play music file from dekstop using javascript?

Tags: javascript, web

I am making a music player website where user can load their music from their local device. How can I do this with javascript or I need to learn some other technology in order to do this.

Comment: go through this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737224/using-local-file-as-audio-src