# HTML5, playing video from local storage

Tags: javascript, android, uiview, android-webview, html5-video

The issue at hand is ..

An cross platform app using either Cordivia or the respective web-view from iOS & Android. This web-view preforms different tasks, where one of them is to show a small range of videos to trains the user, using HTML5.

The issue at hand, is this training is preform there there are absolutely no network access. So all movies is inclued into the app it self.

So at this point, I got a  `public_html/www`   folder where all the pages are located, and a media folder where all the movies are located.

All access the the local media files, are "blocked" on the phone, while everything works out fine in browser level. If i change any of the local media   `source src=http://..`   then everything works out great, but when  `source src="localmedia.mp4"`  - breaks everything.

I've been searching and searching for dealing with this issue, and I can see that a user interaction is mentioned for security ( [Play local (hard-drive) video file with HTML5 video tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885701/play-local-hard-drive-video-file-with-html5-video-tag) ). I relealy dont whan the user to chose a file, i "just" want to play the file defined in that specific page.

I have been searching and searching without any ideal solution but worked out for me, and getting more and more desperate. I've got all the movies playing, I got all the code working in HTML5 - everything is playing out nice, except the  `video`  tag on the phone.

If somone got a running example of playing a local media file from a phone whitout input select, please share ;)