# Preview videos in HTML5 of type .mov

Tags: jquery, video, preview

I'm trying to browse and upload videos using the code given in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dsbonev/cCCZ2/).

```
(function localFileVideoPlayerInit(win) {
    var URL = win.URL || win.webkitURL,
        displayMessage = (function displayMessageInit() {
            var node = document.querySelector('#message');

            return function displayMessage(message, isError) {
                node.innerHTML = message;
                node.className = isError ? 'error' : 'info';
            };
        }()),
        playSelectedFile = function playSelectedFileInit(event) {
            var file = this.files[0];

            var type = file.type;

            var videoNode = document.querySelector('video');

            var canPlay = videoNode.canPlayType(type);

            canPlay = (canPlay === '' ? 'no' : canPlay);

            var message = 'Can play type "' + type + '": ' + canPlay;

            var isError = canPlay === 'no';

            displayMessage(message, isError);

            if (isError) {
                return;
            }

            var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

            videoNode.src = fileURL;
        },
        inputNode = document.querySelector('input');

    if (!URL) {
        displayMessage('Your browser is not ' + 
           '<a href="http://caniuse.com/bloburls">supported</a>!', true);

        return;
    }      inputNode.addEventListener('change', playSelectedFile, false);
}(window));
```

The preview of the file type `.mp4` is working as required but some other file type like `.mov, .avi` etc cannot be previewed

Comment: What OS and browser are you using - different browsers and OS's support different formats? Within the 'package' (i.e. mp4, AVA etc) different codecs may be used for video and audio which again may not be supported on your target system. If you can also give a link to the videos which do not work this should be possible to check.

Comment: Linux with chrome browser.

Comment: I am using ubuntu with chrome browser. The same problem will exists in windows OS too. We can't preview the videos of format .avi, .mov etc using the code mentioned in above fiddle.

Comment: Can you give an example of some videos which do not work?

Comment: Browse any videos of type `.mov` or `.avi` from ur system and it will giving `Can play type "video/quicktime": no` error.

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers support different video containers (mp4, mov, WebM etc) and codecs (h.264, VP8 etc) and unfortunately this tends to change over time also. Chrome does not necessarily even support mp4 out of the box but many systems will have installs that will allow it (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support).

In general if you want to be able to play videos across browsers you need to provide the video in different formats - there is an example of a cross browser approach that is kept up to date here:

- http://v4e.thewikies.com

Unfortunately, this does not help you too much for the specific use case you have - you would need to upload the video and convert it to the different formats first which is presumably not what you want.

It is also in theory possible to convert a video to the necessary formats on the client side using Javascript (e.g. https://bgrins.github.io/videoconverter.js/) but this will be very slow I think and probably not meet your preview needs.