# RoR: How to load a file from a mobile device?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile

I want to play a video file, which is coming from the mobile device's folder.
(say the mobile device's `/storage/emulated/0/Download folder`)
How do I do that with rails? All I see from searching is loading from the server machine.

This is because I do not want to load it from the server machine, because of some limitations.

Is this possible?
If not, do you have any suggestions on how to approach this?
Thanks.

Comment: What are you saying? You want to upload a file from a mobile device to the server and play it? Or do you want to play a video from the mobile device on the mobile device itself? If it's the latter, then I would say it has precious little to do with Rails.

Comment: Its the latter. I want to play a video from the mobile device on the mobile device itself. Meaning its like in a page in my rails app I am embedding the video player for that file.
If it has little to do with Rails, do you have ideas on where this should be asked?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is the closest asnwer.
Will just update the code accordingly to not choose a file anymore.

[Play local (hard-drive) video file with HTML5 video tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885701/play-local-hard-drive-video-file-with-html5-video-tag)