# How can i play local video files within chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video

I have a file called "C:\folder\movie.mp4". How can I play this in chrome? I tried using html5 video tag, but no luck. I see the player but cannot click play.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls><source src="file:///C:/folder/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
```

Comment: Why would any good browser implementation allow this? It's a huge security risk, and has little good uses, if any.

Comment: this question was already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885701/play-local-hard-drive-video-file-with-html5-video-tag

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your code is okay, try using a relative path of the video file instead, for instance, if the video is in the same folder as the HTML document:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls><source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
```

Or, if it's in a subfolder (e.g. "folder") of the HTML root folder:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls><source src="folder/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
```