# How to make an object URL that points to the local File object with GWT?

Tags: gwt, html5-video

How to make an object URL that points to the local File object with GWT?

Would be nice reuse result of com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FileUpload and com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FormPanel.

*URL.createObjectURL()* with GWT (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9349984

Also found this rocket science https://github.com/akjava/html5gwt.

Answer (score -1):

As this is not possible in javascript, this is also not possible in GWT.