# Load video in browser from computer without uploading to server

Tags: laravel, angular, amazon-web-services, video, amazon-s3

I am trying to load a video from the desktop into a browser just for view so that the end user can add some more information like how they want to trim the video before it gets sent to AWS Elastic Transcoder which then sends the file to S3 server.  Could someone help me figure out what the best approach would be?  I do not want to load the video file into the server first just on the browser so that I can gather all details including trimming information before aws is called.

Tech stack is Laravel, Angular

Comment: you say so don't want to use the server so it has nothing to do with laravel. I think you can use the fileapi with javascript, but I have no idea how you can edit a video in it, because you can't just cut the video (maybe with a library). One approach would be to use ffmpeg and cut it on the server.

Comment: As @mimo said, its not possible to do it client side, end user would need more than just "browser".

Comment: @mino, Well the objective was not to edit anything, the video would be sent to AWS Elastic Transcoder as it is, so I just needs to collect Trim details from the end user for which need to load the video on the browser to collect the information.  The actual Transcoding and Trimming would be done by AWS as it is.

Comment: There is a working example included in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9349984/334402