# How to load a local file using, electron and webpack?

Tags: video, webpack, electron

I am developing a video player with electron. And I wanna have an ability to choose a video file from the file system and play it. The path could look like `C://Users/.../...` for win. and `/Users/../../` for OSX. So the problem is Chrome cannot use the `file://` protocol and without the the protocol it's trying to load it from the current host. So is there a way to load a video from OS file system using electron or webpack?

Comment: Did you try using the path without the `file://` prefix ? For example:  `src="C://Users/path/to/video.mp4"`

Comment: Yeah, I tried, Chrome automatically adds `localhost` as host, so it tries to load it like `localhost:8080/C://Users/../`

Comment: Weird, I'm accessing image files in my Electron app, after selecting their path from the electron `select-directory` dialog and using the returned path. Chrome never added `localhost` prefix in my app. Do you parse your files in the "Client Side" or in the Node side ? I'm using *Node's FS* (`var fs = require('fs')`) to parse them. Look at this [electron-video-player](https://github.com/RIAEvangelist/electron-video-player) app, I assume you'll find your answer there.

Answer (score 0):

You can allow the user choose the video, if this will meet your needs, using:

```html
<input type="file" accept="video/*"/>
```

This works on chrome.

There is a nice working example in the fiddle in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9349984/334402

Comment: Thank you, i'll try, hope it'll help