# Preview video and other file dropzone js

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

Anyone know how to create a preview for video and other files in dropzone js ?
I know in documentation dropzone js can accept some files, not image only but i dont know how to create a preview for not image.
Any help will be appreciated :-)

Comment: this is probably exactly what you want to do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9349984/2625645

Comment: if preview with file reader html5 like in your url above, i can make that. But my problem is with drozone js.

Comment: @user8455694 did you ever find a solution?