# Javascript how to get absolute path?

Tags: javascript

How can i get the absolute path of an uploaded file (that has been uploaded by `input file`) and use it as a `<video>`.

Comment: That's a question of your backend set up

Comment: If you wanna know the path of the client that uploads that video, basicly you cant, it's a security feature that all browsers adapt.

Comment: oh can i change the speed of an uploaded file and then download it without getting the filepath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, you cannot get the absolute path of a file picked from a file picker in front-end JavaScript. That would allow websites to potentially see private information, such as the user's name and their operating system. Also, a user might not want the website to see their folder structure and the names of their folders.

Here is a way of using a file picked for a `<video>` tag (You don't need to know the full path of file). I didn't make this, but it will probably help you: http://jsfiddle.net/dsbonev/cCCZ2/

How it works is you create a object url.

```
var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(fileFromFilePicker);
```

Then you can set the `src` attribute of the `<video>` tag.

If you don't want to actually upload the file, then [your question has already been asked and answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885701/play-local-hard-drive-video-file-with-html5-video-tag)